# bootstrap modal contents extend past modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make this:

[image]

...look more like this:

[image]

The page I'm working on:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/scripts/demo/bootstrap-content-extends-past-modal.html

My code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">




<div class="modal fade modal-aside horizontal right events-modal ui-draggable in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; padding-right: 0px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="form-full-event" action="http://local.pap360.com/run.php/reports/admin/timeclock" method="post">
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                            <fieldset>
                                <input type="hidden" id="logID" name="logID" value="&lt;?= $row-&gt;logID ?&gt;">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                        <label>Type</label>
                                        <select id="logType" name="logType" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="">Select Type</option>
                                            <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
                                            <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
                                            <option value="Break">Break</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                        <label>Time In</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="timeIN" name="timeIN" value="" class="form-control dateTime">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                        <label>Time Out</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="timeOUT" name="timeOUT" value="" class="form-control dateTime">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <button type="reset" id="reset" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Cancel</button>
                                        <button type="submit" id="addEntry" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" disabled="">Add Entry</button>
                                        <button type="submit" id="submitChanges" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Update</button>
                                        <!--
                                        <button type="submit" id="updateEntry" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Update</button>
                                        -->
                                        <span id="errorMsg" style="color:red">&nbsp;</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        <!--
                            <button type="submit" id="submitChanges" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Changes</button>
                            -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If I do `$('.modal-content').css('height', '150px');` I get something that looks like the second image but I'd just assume not hard-code the height and have to make adjustments to it if I want to add explanatory text, etc.

If I do `$('fieldset').parent().css('float', 'none');` that kinda fixes the problem but then each form element is on it's own line.

If I didn't care about having a responsive layout and I didn't care about employing the Bootstrap way I could put the different form elements into a table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this class to the modal-body

```
class="modal-body clearfix"
```

Replace this

```
class="modal-body"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59rIs.png)
[image]

[image]
Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a clearfix class to the parent elemet zich contains the box shadow property

Answer (score 0):

You can use panel something like this

```
 <div class="content">
                            <div class="form-horizontal" action="#">
                                <div class="panel panel-flat">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
```

and insert all your controls inside

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra class to your `col-md-12` that is wrapping your `fieldset` and then apply a `float: unset` to it. This way your elements stay inline but your modal's height will have something to calculate against.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the first div child of modal-body, which has class `col-md-12` which has style `float="left"`. Remove `class="col-md-12"` or add `style="float:none"` (or another float style with similar effect).

[image]